# how to capture the first cloned list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to capture the first cloned list using jquery?

```
<ul id=testList>
    <li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test A </p></li>
    <li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test B </p></li>
    <li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test C </p></li>
    <li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test D </p></li>
    <li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test E </p></li>
</ul>
```

My attempt:

```
var firstClonedList = $("#testList li:eq(0)").clone();
alert(firstClonedList.html());
```

Problem:
          The alert is displaying:

```
<input type=checkbox" /><p> Test A </p>
```

correctly but I need the alert to display:

```
<li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test A </p></li>
```

Comment: the code is working exactly as expected though. The `<li>` is in fact being cloned and the `.html()` is giving the DOM objects inside the element which is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `firstClonedList` list contains what you need, but by adding `.html()` you are asking to give the html content of firstClonedList. So just use firstClonedList[0]

```
var firstClonedList = $("#testList li:first").clone();
console.log(firstClonedList[0]);
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var firstClonedList = $("#testList li:eq(0)").clone();
alert($('<div/>').append(firstClonedList).html());​​​​​​​​
```

The idea is to create a `div` as a wrapper for your `li`, and then just call `html()` on the `div`.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/9wLGV/).

Answer (score 2):

you need an outerHTML feature..

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return $( $('<div></div>').html(this.clone()) ).html();
}
```

Now you can use outerHTML wherever you want

`alert(firstClonedList.outerHTML());` will show what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `html` method gets the `innerHTML` property of the element. You want the `outerHTML` proeprty:

```
firstClonedList.prop('outerHTML');
```

There may be some cross-browser issues with this solution however, particularly involving Firefox. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly getting the `li` element whose html representation is

```
<li><input type=checkbox" /><p> Test A </p></li>
```

You are expecting `elem.html()` to return whole html but it will return inner html, inside the `li` element

from jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original
>   document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the
>   quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric
>   characters.

To get the whole source html of the element, you can insert it in another element and then get that element's html e.g.

```
alert($("<div>").append(firstClonedList).html())​
```

see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AsZgz/)

Comment: Not much of an answer, the OP already said that `html()` works correctly but that he needs something different.

Comment: @cambraca, my bad, I was midway writing my answer, first explaining the reason and then the solution, after trying it out in jsfiddle